# jquery trigger click function not working on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I want to make anchor clickable on page load. (which will download an image for me ).
I am using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

here is my anchor tag

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['order_number'];
?>
<a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
```

here is js code which is at the end of the page

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
    var getCanvas; // global variable

    html2canvas(element, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
            getCanvas = canvas;
        }
    });
   // $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {

        var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
        var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
        $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "<?php echo 'product_label_'.$id ?>.png").attr("href", newData);
   // });
    jQuery('#btn-Convert-Html2Image').click();

});
```

I know the trigger function of jquery does this but its not working for me

I have commented the function

```
$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
```

which is working fine when I click it. After commenting this line it should work as the code within this function is now in `document ready` function.

Don't know where I am doing wrong

Comment: Or you can create a function and call it on document ready

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to make a function like so

```
function ClickFunction() {

    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "<?php echo 'product_label_'.$id ?>.png").attr("href", newData);
};

$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on("click",ClickFunction)
```

check out simple example below

```js
function ClickFunction() {

  $("div").css({
    "background-color": "blue"
  })

}
$("button").on("click", ClickFunction)
```

```css
div {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to script to be executed on click of a function as its already working for me. I want it to be executed on page load as mentioned in the question

Comment: oh then instead of `$("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on("click",ClickFunction) ` try calling it just ClickFunction() . if it's not working check console for any errors

Comment: I have tried `ClickFunction() ' way its showing me syntax error on `ClickFunction() { ' curly braces :(

Answer (score 0):

**Try creating a function and calling it on page document ready and click handler**

Please refer below structure of your code for an example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
    var getCanvas; // global variable

    html2canvas(element, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
            getCanvas = canvas;
        }
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', downloadImage);
    downloadImage()
});

function downloadImage{
        var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
        var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
        $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "<?php echo 'product_label_'.$id ?>.png").attr("href", newData);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, still not working. I thought my script is not working so I removed all code from `downloadImage` function and only alert hello world in this function. its not even alerting.